# How to split a Kendo Grid into a child and parent grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, split, grid, row, expand

So I'm having problems with my grid because it has too many columns. What I'd like to do is split this grid into half, having only half of the columns shown in the main grid and the other half in a child grid when row gets expanded.

Basically the data in a row of a parent grid has to be the same as the data in row of a child grid, only different columns shown.

The code below should be transformed into something like this:
[image]

Here's the grid itself:

```
$("#Materials")
    .kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            data: [],
            schema: {
                model: {
                    id: "ID",
                    fields: {
                        ID: { type: "number", editable: false },
                        Code: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        Name: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        ExternalCode1: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        ExternalCode2: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        OtherCode1: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        ServiceMode: { type: "string", editable: false },
                    }
                }
            },
            pageSize: 20
        },
        pageable: true,
        columns: [
            { field: "Code", title:"Code"},
            { field: "Name", title: "Name"},
            { field: "ExternalCode1", title:"External Code1"},
            { field: "ExternalCode2", title:"External Code2"},
            { field: "OtherCode1", title:"Other Code1"},
            { field: "ServiceMode", title:"Service Mode"},
        ],
        editable: false
    });
```

I'm filling the data on document ready for faster pageload performance with an ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the data passed in your `detailInit` event to be used in your child grid.

Try this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lwuvxha/) if this works for you.

Comment: You Sir, are a saviour. Thanks, it does work. I was also wondering if you perhaps know how this could be done with MVC Razor, just for future reference. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry, I am not familiar with MVC Razor.